# How do I cast custom MutableLiveData to custom LiveData?

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

suppose there are 2 classes:

```
class MyLiveData:LiveData<Int>()

class MyMutableLiveData:MutableLiveData<Int>()
```

Casting from `MutableLiveData` to `LiveData` is permitted:

```
val ld1=MutableLiveData<Int>()
val ld2:LiveData<Int> = ld1  //ok
```

But you can't cast your own implementations this way:

```
val mutable=MyMutableLiveData()
val immutable:MyLiveData = mutable //type missmatch
```

I understand that MutableLiveData extends LiveData thats why they are castable.But I can't have `MyMutableLiveData` extending `MyLiveData` as it won't be mutable in this case

Are there any workarounds?
**UPD**:I guess I need to show motivation of extending `LiveData`.I'm trying to implement `MutableLiveDataCollection` which notifies not just value changes via `setValue/postValue` but also value modification like adding new elements.I'm surprised there is no native solution for this.
Anyway to obseve `modify` events there have to be additional observe method.And this method have to be inside immutable part aka `LiveDataCollection` because views will call it.Inheritance is natural solution here IMHO.

Comment: Data type for my `LiveData` is `ArrayList`.I need specific observe method which subscribes to observe events like `new items were added to array`

Comment: what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea sits in the `MutableLiveData` class.The only thing this class does - is it changes access modifiers on `setValue/postValue` methods.I can do the same trick.Therefore the final code will be:

```
open class LiveDataCollection<K,
                              L:MutableCollection<K>,
                              M:Collection<K>>: LiveData<L>() {
    private var active=false
    private var diffObservers = ArrayList<Observer<M>>()
    fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, valueObserver: Observer<L>, diffObserver: Observer<M>) {
        super.observe(owner,valueObserver)
        diffObservers.add(diffObserver)
    }
    protected open fun addItems(toAdd:M) {
        value?.addAll(toAdd)
        if (active)
            for (observer in diffObservers)
                observer.onChanged(toAdd)
    }
    override fun removeObservers(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.removeObservers(owner)
        diffObservers= ArrayList()
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        active=true
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        active=false
    }
}

class MutableLiveDataCollection<K,L:MutableCollection<K>,
                                  M:Collection<K>>: LiveDataCollection<K,L,M>() {
    public override fun addItems(toAdd:M) {
        super.addItems(toAdd)
    }

    public override fun postValue(value: L) {
        super.postValue(value)
    }

    public override fun setValue(value: L) {
        super.setValue(value)
    }
}
```